# Extracting element names from XML in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml doc like this:

```
  <root>
     <e1>
       <l2>
       ..
       </l2>
     </e1>
     <e2>
      ...
     </e2>
     ...
    </root>
```

I want to extract the list of direct children of an element only the element tag name, for example for root I only want to get e1, and e2 (just the tag(element)name not the whole element) and for e1 I want to get l2 again just the tagname

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<root>
     <e1>
       <l2>
         <data1>test</data1>
       </l2>
       <l3>
         <data3>test3</data3>
       </l3>
     </e1>
     <e2>
        <data1>test</data1>
        <data2>test2</data2>
     </e2>
    </root>'
```

To get the immediate descendant nodes under `<root>`, you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(20)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/root/*') AS XT(XC)
```

Returns:

```
e1
e2
```

And this query to get the descendants of `<e2>`:

```
SELECT
    XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(20)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/root/e2/*') AS XT(XC)
```

returns:

```
data1
data2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine.I wonder where this has been documented 'local-name'?

Comment: @FredJand: [see here - official MSDN documentation by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx)